# Hot to fetch RestLet Data from javascript fetch function?

Tags: netsuite

I have a GET restlet to search for all employees in my Netsuite account.
I want to use fetch js function in my react application to get all the data from the restlet.
I have tried with postman to see and its works well there, but now I need to implement it on my react app
Where should I put the tokens and all the headers?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a public app all your tokens should only be stored server side -- not in your react app on the client.

If this is a react app embedded in the UI then you don't need authentication because Netsuite allows internal restlet calls from the logged in user (as long as the restlet audiencing includes them).

The simplest thing to set up is to have your suitelet return JSON in response to a query with an action parameter

For local development I rely a lot on mock-server. Logged in to Netsuite I hit the suitelet with the action param and populate the mock-server files. Local dev just hits mock server.
A problem with Restlets (also a feature) is that they run with the permissions of the authenticated user. A suitelet can be run as administrator with audiencing to allow controlled access to resources that the users shouldn’t have unrestricted read or write access to.

Comment: I am creating a react app to work on a suitelet UI but I need it to work on my local host too when I am building it.

Comment: I expanded my answer. You might want to edit your question  with your comment too so that the whole question and answer is more helpful to others

Comment: For example how can i call a restlet from 3d side company? I need the tokens right?
so I need to call it from my local machine

Comment: Yes for  a 3rd party Restlet, i.e. one hosted in another Netsuite account.  But the tokens should still be stored server side -- not in your React app.